# git: check-in a file in a symlink directory fails

Tags: linux, git, symlink

I have a project directory with *regular-files* **and** *generated-files* by a tool.
The *generated-files* are as important as the *regular-files* → I want to have the *generated-files* in the **git** repository too.

the problem is that I use a *build-directory* in a *memory-file-system* and a *source-directory* on a *regular-file-system*. the *generated-files* are in a subdirectory of the *build-file-system* called *gen* and the *gen* is *soft-link* to the *source-file-system*

**build**

```
...
gen/libsq3sqlite3.meta
...
```

**source**

```
...
gen -> /path/to/build/gen
...
```

If I do a `git add gen/libsq3sqlite3.meta` I get the error message

- fatal: pathspec 'gen/libsq3sqlite3.meta' is beyond a symbolic link

If I do a `readlink -f gen/libsq3sqlite3.meta` first I get the real path

- /some/real/path/to/gen/libsq3sqlite3.meta

And if I use this *real-path* I get

- fatal: /some/real/path/to/gen/libsq3sqlite3.meta: '/some/real/path/to/gen/libsq3sqlite3.meta' is outside repository at '/my/rep/project'

**I want to have**

1. *git* should accept the *gen-subdirectory* as *regular-directory*
2. *git* should treat every file **in** the *gen-subdirectory* as *regular-file*
3. *git* should treat the *gen-subdirectory* **always** relative to the *source-directory* and **always** use the *source-directory-path* of the *file* and **not** the *build-directory-path*

Comment: I don't think anything like this is possible. Git doesn't map paths. If you want to add something to a repository the files must be in the working tree. Outside files cannot be added.

Comment: If you are on a capable OS, you may be able to use a bind-mount instead of a symbolic link for the `gen` directory.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to replace the *soft-link* with a `mount` :

→ `mount --bind srcDir tgtDir`

the only problem is that this mount **have** to be done as *root* hand does **not** survive a reboot without add into the `/etc/fstab` file